# Difference of elements of 2 sorted arrays within given interval

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Let us assume that  we have 2 sorted arrays A and B of integers and a given interval [L,M] . If x is an element of A and y an element of B ,our task is to find all pairs of (x,y) that hold the following property: L<=y-x<=M.
Which is the most suitable algorithm for that purpose?

So far ,I have considered the following solution:
Brute force. Check the difference of all possible pairs of elements with a double loop .Complexity O(n^2).

A slightly different version of the previous solution is to make use of the fact that arrays are sorted by not checking the elements of A ,once difference gets out of interval .Complexity would still be O(n^2) but hopefully our program would run faster at an average case.

However ,I believe that O(n^2) is not optimal .Is there an algorithm with better complexity?

Comment: Could you clarify in your question when you are referring to x, y, L, and M as their index or the value at that index? A small example (just 5 or 6 values in each array) would really help as well.

Comment: To give an example ,let as assume that A ={ 1,2,3}  , B={10,12,15}  , L=12,M=14.  We want 12<=y-x <=14 (x are the elements of A ,y are the elements of B)  .In our case ,the correct pairs are (1,15) and (2,15) ,because  12<=15-1<=14 and 12<=15-2<=14 . All other possible pairs are not suitable.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution.

Have a pointer at the beginning of each array say `i` for array A and `j` for array B.

Calculate the difference between B[j] and A[i].

If it is less than `L`, increment the pointer in array B[], i.e increment `j` by 1

If it is more than `M`, increment `i`, i.e pointer of A.

If the difference is in between, then do the following:

- search for the position of an element whose value is `B[j]-A[i]-L` or the nearest
  element whose value is lesser than `(B[j]-A[i])-L` in array A. This
  takes `O(logN)` time. Say the position is `p`. Increment the count of
  (x,y) pairs by `p-i+1`
- Increment only pointer `j`

My solution only counts the number of possible (x,y) pairs in `O(NlogN)` time

For `A=[1,2,3]` and `B=[10,12,15]` and `L=12` and `M=14`, answer is `3`.

Hope this helps. I leave it up to you, to implement the solution

**Edit:** Enumerating all the possible (x,y) pairs would take `O(N^2)` worst case time. We will be able to return the *count* of such pairs (x,y) in `O(NlogN)` time. Sorry for not clarifying it earlier.

**Edit2:** I am attaching a sample implementation of my proposed method below:

```
def binsearch(a, x):

    low = 0
    high = len(a)-1
    while(low<=high):
        mid = (low+high)/2
        if a[mid] == x:
            return mid
        elif a[mid]<x:
            k = mid
            low = low + mid
        else:
            high = high - mid

    return k

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [10, 12, 15, 16]
i = 0
j = 0

lenA = len(a)
lenB = len(b)

L = 12
M = 14
count = 0 
result = []
while i<lenA and j<lenB:
    if b[j] - a[i] < L:
        j = j + 1
    elif b[j] - a[i] > M:
        i = i + 1
    else:
        p = binsearch(a,b[j]-L)
        count = count + p - i + 1
        j = j + 1

print "number of (x,y) pairs: ", count
```

Comment: May I ask a question?It may be simple ,but I am missing something.

Comment: "If the difference is in between, then store the current pair, i.e, A[i] and B[j]" .After I store that pair ,what should my next step be?If I choose to increase either i or j ,I am afraid that I might loose some pairs.

Comment: O(nlogn) is definitely much better than O(n^2) .The answer was indeed very useful!Thanks! Could an algorithm of O(n) possibly exist though?

Answer (score 0):

Because it's possible for every combination to be in the specified range, the worst-case is O([A][B]), which is basically O(n^2)

However, if you want the best simple algorithm, this is what I've come up with. It starts similarly to user-targaryen's algorithm, but handles overlaps in a simplistic fashion

```
Create three variables: x,y,Z and s (set all to 0)
Create a boolean 'success' and set to false
Calculate Z = B[y] - A[x]
if Z < L
    increment y
if Z >= L and <= M
    if success is false
        set s = y
        set success = true
    increment y
    store x,y
if Z > M
    set y = s   //this may seem inefficient with my current example
                //but you'll see the necessity if you have a sorted list with duplicate values)
                //you can just change the A from my example to {1,1,2,2,3} to see what I mean
    set success = false
```

an example:
A = {1,2,3,4,5}
B = {3,4,5,6,7}
L = 2, M = 3

In this example, the first pair is x,y. The second number is s. The third pair is the values A[x] and B[y]. The fourth number is Z, the difference between A[x] and B[y]. The final value is X for not a match and O for a match

```
0,0 - 0 - 1,3 = 2 O
    increment y
0,1 - 0 - 1,4 = 3 O
    increment y
0,2 - 0 - 1,5 = 4 X
    //this is the tricky part. Look closely at the changes this makes
    set y to s
    increment x
1,0 - 0 - 2,3 = 1 X
    increment y
1,1 - 0 - 2,4 = 2 O
    set s = y, set success = true
    increment y
1,2 - 1 - 2,5 = 3 O
    increment y
1,3 - 1 - 2,6 = 4 X
    set y to s
    increment x
2,1 - 1 - 3,4 = 1 X
    increment y
2,2 - 1 - 3,5 = 2 O
    set s = y, set success = true
    increment y
2,3 - 2 - 3,6 = 3 O
... and so on
```